# "This webpage has a redirect loop" with angularjs + rails + devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, devise

I know theres a lot about redirect problem with angularjs in here, but so far didnt see something like this problem, I am using Rails as API server with Devise, I get to loggin to Devise with ajax/json just fine, but when I refresh a page been logged in where I need to be logged to see it, I get the "redirect loop" error. like this:
**Go to the app `0.0.0.0:3000/#/`, need to be logged in so this redirects me to: `0.0.0.0:3000/#/login`, once there I loggin and get redirected to `0.0.0.0:3000/#/`, til there all fine, but if now I do refresh or go to another, let say `0.0.0.0:3000/#/events/new`, and then do the refresh I get the `redirect loop` error.**

Heres the code:

app.js

```
angular.module("eventnote", ['eventServices', 'loginServices', 'pruebaS', 'countrySelect']).config(['$httpProvider', function(provider){
    provider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  }]).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){//start to configure the interceptor
    var interceptor = function($q, $location, $rootScope) {
        return function(promise){
            return promise.then(function(response){return response;}, function(response){
                console.log(response.status);
                if (response.status == 401){//just the 401 responses 
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unathorized');
                    $location.path('/login');
                    return response;
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        }
    };
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);//add the interceptor
}]).config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/events/new", {templateUrl: 'ang/create.html', controller: NewEventsCtrl})
    .when("/events/:id/edit", {templateUrl: 'ang/edit.html', controller: UpdateCtrl })
    .when("/login", {templateUrl: "ang/login.html", controller: LoginCtrl})
    .when("/", {templateUrl: 'ang/home.html', controller: HomeCtrl})
}]);
```

controller.js:

```
function HomeCtrl ($scope, Prueba) {
    $scope.state = "";
    $scope.obj = Prueba.probar(function(re) { $scope.state = re.mensaje}, function(re){ $scope.state = re.data.error;});
    $scope.error = $scope.obj.error;
}

function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, Login, Logout){
 $scope.user = {}; 

 $scope.login = function(user){
        var u = new Login({user:{email: user.email, password: user.password}});
        u.$log_in(function(result){
            $location.path('/');
        });
 }
}
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('loginServices', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Login', function($resource){
    return $resource('users/sign_in.json', {}, {
        log_in: {method: 'POST'}
    });
}).factory('Logout', function($resource){
    return $resource('users/sign_out.json', {},{
        log_out: {method: 'DELETE'}
    });
});
angular.module('pruebaS', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Prueba', function($resource){
    return $resource('api/prueba', {}, {
        probar: {method: 'GET'}
    });
});
```

Since the problem only happens when I am logged in I think it may be the `interceptor`, cuz I can refresh just fine when I am unauthenticated. hope someone can help me, thanks¡

Answer (score 0):

fixed, aparently the problem was in the rails routes file, I had:

```
 devise_scope :user do
   root 'devise/sessions#new'
 end
```

and change it to :

```
devise_scope :user do
 root 'pages#index'
end
```

not sure if this I really need to user to have a root since I am workin all the view and routing on the client side, but for now this did fix it, weird since I thou devise would not do redirect_to when using json format but anyway.